# How do I add a line from the end of a sentence to the edge of the paper in Pages?

Tags: pages

If I have some text like:

> Work Experience
>
> Taco Bell
>
> Apple Store
>
> Disneyland

and I want a line drawn from the end of “Work Experience” to the right side of the page (to the end of the page margin, that is), is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 2):

The easy way to do this is to select the first line - change the text style to be underline and add tabs after the “e” in experience.

This way, the underline goes as far right as you please.

[image: Picture of the solution rendered in pages for iPad]

Adding a horizontal line is fine as well if you can accept a line break under the heading and before the list starts.

Both of these work on iOS pages, web app pages as well.

Comment: An underlined line can be had also through a one-row table with only a bottom border but that is cumbersome to create compared with the two options described above.